# JavaScript Split Function - Split After Parentheses and Comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

I have a list of ID's, that I am trying to separate using JavaScript split() function. Each of the ID's have the following format:

**Format Examples**

```
(51.87,0.2125) // Lat and Long values with comma separation
(48.87,0.3130)
```

In JavaScript these ID's are each stored in a value attribute in a string.

**Example:**

```
(48.87,0.3130),(51.87,0.2125),(48.87,0.3130),(51.87,0.2125)
```

My goal is to use the split function after the closing parentheses and comma. How can I use the split function taking into account closing parentheses and comma?

Currently, I have this:

```
 var location_id = $(this).find("input").val().split(',');
```

**Desired Output**

```
 ["(48.87,0.3130)","(51.87,0.2125)","(48.87,0.3130)","(51.87,0.2125)"]
```

Comment: What is your desired output for the provided example input?

Comment: @Skyler ["(48.87,0.3130)","(51.87,0.2125)","(48.87,0.3130)","(51.87,0.2125)"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression `/\(\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+\)/g`

```js
var str = '(48.87,0.3130),(51.87,0.2125),(48.87,0.3130),(51.87,0.2125)';
console.log(str.match(/\(\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+\)/g))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = "(48.87,0.3130),(51.87,0.2125),(48.87,0.3130),(51.87,0.2125)";

// Approach 1
var formattedData = data.split("),").map((el) => {
  return el.indexOf(")")==-1 ? el + ")": el;
});
console.log(formattedData);


// Approach 2 (replace , with | and then split using | )
formattedData2 = data.replace(/\),/g, ")|").split("|");
console.log(formattedData2);
```

Answer (score 1):

See comments inline:

```js
var s = "(48.87,0.3130),(51.87,0.2125),(48.87,0.3130),(51.87,0.2125)";
var location_id = s.split('),');

location_id.forEach(function(loc, i, ary) {
  // Put parens around the value with the left over parens removed
  ary[i] = "(" + loc.replace("(","").replace(")", "") + ")";
}); 
console.log(location_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I could think of is to split it by `,(` , then map it removing all the `(` and `)` as the first and last entries will be inconsistent, then tacking the `(` and `)` back on:

```js
const str = '(48.87,0.3130),(51.87,0.2125),(48.87,0.3130),(51.87,0.2125)';

const result = str.split(',(')
    .map(x => '(' + x.replace('(','').replace(')','') + ')');

console.log(result);
```